# How to create a simple GStreamer Source Plugin?

Tags: c++, c, plugins, gstreamer, multimedia

I was reading the `GStreamer` plugin guide and it had a chapter on plugin source but it was one paragraph long. Does anyone have any tips/tutorials on how to create a basic source plugin?

I was thinking about reading a source plugin in `gstreamer` but they are too complex. Any simple ones I could look at that does the basics?